# .ajax Temporarily halting the return to .ajax from a PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

```
            $.ajax({ url: 'buildquery.php',
            data: {action: 'test'},
            type: 'post',
            success: function(output) {
                alert(output);
            }
        });

<?php
echo "Hello World!";
die();
?>
```

In this particular case I would like the PHP script to halt so I can see the output in my browser window and not return into the .ajax function. This would be for debugging purposes so I can output some data so my user can see the output while the application is under construction. Can this be done? Alternatives? I though about using the submit function of the form but this is going to cause some code changes between debug and release builds. Thanks for any commentary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest just writing it to a file in the php script. Or use firebug. Or chrome developer tools. (Click network and select XHR)

Comment: I see I can click the name of the file and see a preview which contains the output I want to see. I didn't know this. Thank you kindly for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, what do you mean by halting the php script? and what output do you want to see? You can just use chrome dev tools or firebug if you want to debug your application. In chrome dev tools you can see the network requests(ajax requests) on the network tab. On firebug you can see it on the console. Just use console.log() to log something on the console.